# Why can't we use "to" in "I saw something to approach me."?

Tags: sentence-construction, to-infinitive

> I saw something to approach me.

I know that we wouldn't use to here, but I can't find an explanation as to why not.

Answer (score 1):

> - *I saw something to approach me.*

This is ungrammatical. Verbs of sensory perception like *see, hear, feel* etc. take bare infinitivals (the kind without *to*) as complement, not *to* infinitivals.

*See* can take a *to* infinitival, as in *He was seen to be an imposter*, but this is a different sense of *see*, where it is a matter of mental inference, not sensory perception.

And *see* can also take gerund-participial clausal complements, e.g. *The driver was seen leaving the scene of the accident*.

Answer (score -1):

Because something approaching you is an ongoing action, which requires [a continuous form](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous) of the verb. "To approach" is the base form of the verb. So the correct sentece is:

"I saw something approaching me".

*This has nothing to do with "see" earlier on in the sentence*, for example:
"I knew something was approaching me" would need the same kind of structure.